# Count by X not completing it's loop

Tags: javascript

I really don't understand why this loop is not working as expected, please see the example below also, is there a better way of doing this?

```
   function countBy(x, n) {
      var z = [];
      for (let i = x; i + x < x * n; i = i + x) {
        z.push(i);
      }
      return z;
    }
```

**Expected:** '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]', **instead got:** '[1, 2, 3]' (x: 1, n: 5)
**Expected:** '[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]', **instead got:** '[2, 4, 6]' (x: 2, n: 10)

Comment: @Teemu Woops, added behind the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `x` is 1 and `n` is 5, `i` will go from 1 up to 4. When `i` is 4, the loop will stop because 1 + 4 is not less than 1 * 5.

Similarly for the case of `x` as 2 and `n` as 10. The loop condition is written such that it terminates too early for your requirements. It should be

```
for (let i = x; i <= x * n; i = i + x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The result you do not expect is correct.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
function countBy(x, n) {
      var z = [];
      for (let i = x; i < x * (n-1); i = i + x) {
        z.push(i);
      }
      return z;
    }
```

which is equivalent to:

```
function countBy(x, n) {
      var z = [];
      for (let i = x; i <= x * (n-2); i = i + x) {
        z.push(i);
      }
      return z;
    }
```

This means when `n` is 5, the loop will only work until `i` is 3 times x.

The correct code would be:

```
   function countBy(x, n) {
      var z = [];
      for (let i = x; i <= x * n; i = i + x) {
        z.push(i);
      }
      return z;
    }
```

However, to match your second example the code needs to be:

```
   function countBy(x, n) {
      var z = [];
      for (let i = x; i <= n; i = i + x) {
        z.push(i);
      }
      return z;
    }
```

Only you know which version you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want to count by x to n, so try this:

```js
 function countBy(x, n) {
    var z = [];
    for (let i = x; i <= n; i = i + x) {
      z.push(i);
    }
    return z;
}
    
console.log(countBy(1,5))
console.log(countBy(2,10))
console.log(countBy(3,10))
```